# How to tell what Ruby string starts with?

Tags: ruby, string, character

I need to discover if the first element of a string is a char or not.
Example:

```
string_1 = "Smith has 30 years"   ----->  TRUE (first element is a character)
string_2 = "20/12/2013 Good Day"  ----->  FALSE (first element is not a character)
string_3 = "<My name is John>"    ----->  FALSE (first element is not a character)
```

Using ".initial" I'm able to access to the first element of each string, but then I don't know to do the test

Comment: Any element of a string is a _character_, perhaps you mean a _letter_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean checking if first element in string is letter, you could do:

```
string[0].match(/[a-zA-Z]/)
```

or, as Arup Rakshit suggested, you can use `i` option in your regexp to ignore case:

```
string[0].match(/[a-z]/i)
```

These lines will return either `MatchData` if tested string starts with letter or `nil` if it doesn't. If you want `true` and `false` values, you can do:

```
!!string[0].match(/[a-z]/i)
```

Comment: Will 'initial' method work with a string in Ruby?

Comment: @AlokAnand I don't know what is this `initial` method, so I removed it from my answer.

Comment: @MarekLipka I had got error while trying that, then I asked you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below :

```
string[/\A[a-z]/i]
```

Look this - [`str[regexp] → new_str or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

In Ruby `nil` and `false` object considered as having *falsy* value.

Or use [`Regexp#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) as below :

```
irb(main):001:0>  /\A[a-z]/i === 'aaa'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>  /\A[a-z]/i === '2aa'
=> false
```

Comment: One point `/^[a-z]/i === "12345\nfoo" # => true`.

Comment: @sawa Thank you very much.. I was wondering the difference between `^` and `\A`.. Now got it.. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want to know is there Ruby libraries like SciPy & NumPy of Python. I need scientific libraries in Ruby for a project.

Comment: Not good or never read Python

Comment: Not even I, but came to know about them, but in Ruby do you know libraries for scientific tasks??

Comment: @AlokAnand Good place - https://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/ruby ... Within 30 mins you would get reply.. and If you post, give me the link also.

Answer (score 1):

This detects if the initial character is a letter (alphabet or underscore; not whether it is a character).

```
string =~ /\A\w/
```

Comment: One point `\w` includes `_` also... See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following:--

```
regex = /[a-zA-Z]/

str[0][regex]
#=> either a letter or nil

str[0][regex].kind_of?(String)
#=> true if first letter matches the regex or false if match return nil.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
2.0.0-p247 :042 > /^[a-zA-Z]/ === 'Smith has 30 \n years'
 => true 
OR
2.0.0-p247 :042 > /\A[a-zA-Z]/ === "Smith has \n 30 years"
 => true


2.0.0-p247 :042 > /^[a-zA-Z]/ === '20/12/2013 \n Good Day'
 => false 
OR
2.0.0-p247 :042 > /\A[a-zA-Z]/ === "20/12/2013 \n Good Day"
 => false


2.0.0-p247 :042 > /^[a-zA-Z]/ === '<My name is \n John>'
 => false 
OR
2.0.0-p247 :042 > /\A[a-zA-Z]/ === "<My name \n is John>"
 => false
```

Comment: I am holding the same answer... :-)

Comment: There is minor diff. You can either use ^ OR \A to check the starting character in Ruby regex

Comment: Correct is `\A`. Look [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807588/how-to-tell-what-ruby-string-starts-with/22807694?noredirect=1#comment34781715_22807694)

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Thanks for pointing out. If you represent your string in double quotes, then only it will interpret delimiters like '\n'. If we use single quotes, it won't be an issue.